# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am developing Insatgram like app. I'm running into the problem where I get a

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of
>   undefined"

I have a very similar component that takes an id from the url, using the same method, and it works fine. I'm confused as to why one is working and another isn't.

and also another Problem in Redirect to Other page I get a "this.props.history.push cannot read property 'props' of undefined" error displayed.

Follow.js:

```
import Popupfollower from '../Layout/Popupfollowfollower';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class follow extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        showfollowerPopup: false,
        showfollowingPopup: false,
        Follow:[]
    }
}

togglePopfollower = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        showfollowerPopup: !this.state.showfollowerPopup
    });

    e.preventDefault();


};
togglePopfollowing = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        showfollowingPopup: !this.state.showfollowingPopup
    });
    e.preventDefault();
};
componentDidMount() {  

  var  guid= this.props.match.params.id; - >>>This is Working Fine

  var access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  var username = localStorage.getItem('user');
 // var guid= localStorage.getItem('Guiid'); 

  axios.get('http://localhost:xxxx/Api/Authenticate/Getfollowingdetails'+'/'+ guid,  { headers: { Authorization: access_token,Username:username } }).then(response => {
     // console.log(response.data)  
      if(response.status=="200")
      {
         this.setState({
           Follow:response.data
         })
         console.log(this.state.Follow)
      }
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
       alert("Your Session time expired.Please Login Again."+error);
       this.props.history.push('/');   - >>>This is Not Working 
   })

}

render() {



    return (
        <div id="react-root">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title> Follower • Instagram</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/insta.ico" />
            </Helmet>
            <section className="_9eogI E3X2T">
            <Header/>
                <div></div>
                <main className="SCxLW  o64aR" role="main">
                    <div className="v9tJq  VfzDr">
                    {                 
                    this.state.Follow.map((follow)=>{
                    return (
                        follow.length != 0?

                        <header className="vtbgv">
                            <div className="XjzKX">
                                <div className="RR-M-" role="button" tabIndex="0">
                                    <canvas className="CfWVH" height="168" width="168" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '-9px', left: '-9px', width: '168px', height: '168px' }}></canvas>
                                    <span className="_2dbep " role="link" tabIndex="0" style={{ width: '150px', height: '150px' }}><img alt="" className="_6q-tv" src={require("../../img/Profile/"+follow.UserImage)}  /></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <section className="zwlfE">
                                <div className="nZSzR">
                    <h1 className="_7UhW9       fKFbl yUEEX   KV-D4            fDxYl     ">{follow.Username}</h1>
                                    <div className="Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm">
                                        <span className="BY3EC  bqE32">
                                            <span className="vBF20 _1OSdk">
                                                <button className="_5f5mN    -fzfL     _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">Following</button>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="AFWDX">
                                        <button className="dCJp8 afkep">
                                            <span aria-label="Options" className="sprite _horizontal__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <ul className="k9GMp">
                                    <li className="Y8-fY ">
                                        <span className="-nal3">
                                            <span className="g47SY ">{follow.Post_count}</span>
                                            posts
                                        </span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="Y8-fY ">
                                        <a className="-nal3" onClick={this.togglePopfollower} href="">
                                             <span className="g47SY ">{follow.Follower_count}</span>{this.state.showfollowerPopup ? <Popupfollower toggle={this.togglePopfollower} /> : null}
                                            followers
                                       </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="Y8-fY " >
                                        <a className="-nal3" onClick={this.togglePopfollowing} href="">
                                          <span className="g47SY ">{follow.Following_count}</span>{this.state.showfollowingPopup ? <Popupfollowing toggle={this.togglePopfollowing} /> : null}
                                            following
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div className="-vDIg">
                                   <h1 className="">{follow.Fullname}</h1>
                                   <a className="yLUwa" href="" rel="me nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{follow.Website}</a>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </header>

                        :null
                    );
                })
                }
                        <div className="fx7hk">
                            <a href="" className="_9VEo1 T-jvg">
                                <span className="smsjF">
                                    <div className="spritesave"></div>
                                    <span className="PJXu4">Posts</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        {
                             this.state.Follow.map((follow)=>{
                                return (
                                    follow.length != 0?
                        <div className="_2z6nI">
                            <article className="ySN3v">
                                <div>
                                    <div style={{ flexdirection: 'column', paddingbottom: '0px', paddingtop: '0px' }}>
                                        <div className="Nnq7C weEfm">
                                            <div className="v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w">
                                                {
                                            follow.UserPost.map(post =>{
                                          return ( 
                                                <a href="">
                                                    <div className="eLAPa">
                                                        <div className="KL4Bh">
                                                            <img alt="" className="FFVAD" decoding="auto" sizes="293px" src={require("../../img/Post/"+post.UploadFile)}  style={{ objectfit: 'cover' }} />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="_9AhH0"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="qn-0x" style={{ backgroundcolor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)', display: 'none' }}><ul className="Ln-UN"><li className="-V_eO"><span>114</span><span className="_1P1TY spriteheart"></span></li><li className="-V_eO"><span>1</span><span className="_1P1TY spritebubble"></span></li></ul></div>
                                                </a>
                                                );
                                            })
                                        }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                           :null
                           );
                       })
                     }
                    </div>

                </main>
                <Footer/>
            </section>
        </div >
    )
}
}

    export default follow
```

PopupFollower.Js

```
class Popupfollowfollower extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    var files;
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
        Follow:[]
    }
}

handleClick = (e) => {
  //  this.props.history.push('/profile')
     this.props.toggle();
     e.preventDefault();
};
componentDidMount() {         

    this.follow();
}
follow= (e) => {

    var  guid= this.props.match.params.id; - >>>This is Not Working 


  var access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  var username = localStorage.getItem('user');
  //var guid= localStorage.getItem('Guiid'); 

  axios.get('http://localhost:xxxx/Api/Authenticate/Getfollowfollowerdetails'+'/'+ guid,  { headers: { Authorization: access_token,Username:username } }).then(response => {

      if(response.status=="200")
      {
         this.setState({
           Follow:response.data
         })
         console.log(this.state.Follow)
      }
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
       alert("Your Session time expired.Please Login Again."+error);
       this.props.history.push('/'); - >>>This is Not Working 
   })

}

Follow(e,guid){
    console.log(guid)
    var id= localStorage.getItem('Guiid');   
    if(guid==id)
    {

      this.props.history.push('/follow/'+guid);
    }else{
      this.props.history.push('/follow/'+guid);
    }

 }
render() {
    return (
        <div className="RnEpo Yx5HN" role="presentation">
            <div className="pbNvD  fPMEg   " role="dialog">
                <div>
                    <div className="eiUFA">
                        <div className="WaOAr"></div>
                        <h1 className="m82CD">Follower</h1>
                        <div className="WaOAr">
                            <button className="wpO6b " type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                <svg aria-label="Close" className="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path clipRule="evenodd" d="M41.1 9.1l-15 15L41 39c.6.6.6 1.5 0 2.1s-1.5.6-2.1 0L24 26.1l-14.9 15c-.6.6-1.5.6-2.1 0-.6-.6-.6-1.5 0-2.1l14.9-15-15-15c-.6-.6-.6-1.5 0-2.1s1.5-.6 2.1 0l15 15 15-15c.6-.6 1.5-.6 2.1 0 .6.6.6 1.6 0 2.2z" fillRule="evenodd"></path>
                                </svg></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        vwCYk         i0EQd  ">
                    <div style={{ height: '356px', overflow: 'hidden auto' }}>
                        <div style={{ flexDirection: 'column', paddingBottom: '795px', paddingTop: '0px' }}>
                        {                 
                   this.state.Follow.map((follow)=>{

                 return (

                   follow.User.length != 0?
                    follow.User.map(record =>{
                       return  (
                            <div className="    Igw0E   rBNOH        eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm    XfCBB  HVWg4 ">
                                <div className="   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm       yC0tu   ">
                                    <div className="RR-M- " role="button">
                                        <canvas className="CfWVH" height="54" width="54" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '-5px', left: '-5px', width: '54px', height: '54px' }}></canvas>
                                        <a className="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="" onClick={(e) => this.Follow(e,record.User_Guiid)}style={{ width: '44px', height: '44px' }}><img alt="mudasir_magry's profile picture" className="_6q-tv" src={require("../../img/Profile/"+record.UserImage)} /></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="  Igw0E     IwRSH        YBx95      vwCYk    ">
                                    <div className="  Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm ">
                                        <div className="_7UhW9   xLCgt      MMzan  KV-D4            fDxYl     ">
                                            <a title="mudasir_magry" href="" onClick={(e) => this.Follow(e,record.User_Guiid)}>
                                                <div className="  Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm ">
                                                    <div className="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm KV-D4            fDxYl      rWtOq">
                                                        <div className="   Igw0E   rBNOH        eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm   ">{record.Username}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="   Igw0E   rBNOH  YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm    soMvl  ">
                                        <button className="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="button">Follow</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             )
                            })
                                 :null
                                 )
                                     })
                                 } 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Popupfollowfollower;
```

App.js

```
<Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route path='/follow/:id' component={Follow} />
        <Route path='/popupfollowfollower' component={Popupfollowfollower} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Your catch block isn't binded and this `this.props` is undefined.

Comment: i am not clear in your answer and why you closed my question.i need clear answer otherwise not closed my question.

Comment: Clear answer is `.catch((error) => {
       alert("Your Session time expired.Please Login Again."+error);
       this.props.history.push('/'); 
   })` exactly as mentioned in the duplicate post. The reason behind the issue is also mentioned there if you care to have a look

Comment: I am asked two question. var  guid= this.props.match.params.id; - >>>This is Working Fine.Error displayed "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" .Where is answer this question.

Comment: Working fine isn't a question buddy. Anyways, it works fine because there this refers to the correct context as `follow` is is implemented as an arrow function

Comment: Popupfollowfollower component isn't rendered on a route that has `id` in match.params. so obviously it will throw you an error

Comment: so finally what is the solution. where i am doing wrong ..my first question....

Comment: Why does `Popupfollowfollower` need Id. If it does, then the route must be `'/popupfollowfollower/:id'`

Comment: id need get the follower details.so i am getting the id from url. please check my code(Popupfollower)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213227/discussion-between-dotnet-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use the `catch` block there like this:

```
.catch(error => { 
alert("Your Session time expired.Please Login Again."+error); 
this.props.history.push('/'); 
});
```